# Verify Log Messages written by Play!'s Logger class

Tags: java, testing, logging, playframework

When writing tests, is it possible to verify messages that have been written by Play!'s logger class?

So for example, if the production code below is executed:

```
Logger.error("boo boo");
```

In my test, am I able to verify that the message `boo boo` was written as an error to the logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to write your own log appender, which puts all data into a List. Then you can analyse the List at end of the test. Perhaps you can download such a logger from some sites.
Another possibility is to use easymock to mock the appender, but I think this is more difficult, because you can't produce easily the expected LogEvent.